# I want to set the background color as the color picked from my CMFCColorButton

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

I have the color picked from my `CMFCColorButton` and now I want to set it to the background (if it's not already the current color).

I can't seem to figure out how, so I would really appreciate your help and explanation.

```
void CMainFrame::OnColor()
{
    // m_TextColors is the ID of the color button I created in the resource editor.
    CMFCRibbonColorButton* pColorBtn = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonColorButton, m_wndRibbonBar.FindByID(m_TextColors));
    COLORREF color = pColorBtn->GetColor();
    CWnd* pwndParent = this->GetParent();
    CRect rcClient;
    pwndParent->GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    if (color != GetSysColor(COLOR_BACKGROUND)) {
        CBrush brush;
        CClientDC dc(this);
        brush.CreateSolidBrush(color);
        dc.FillRect(rcClient, &brush);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox(_T("Same Color."), MB_OK);
    }
}
```

I made some changes:

```
void CMainFrame::OnColor()
{
    // m_TextColors is the ID of the color button I created in the resource editor.
    CMFCRibbonColorButton* pColorBtn = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonColorButton, m_wndRibbonBar.FindByID(m_TextColors));
    COLORREF color = pColorBtn->GetColor();
    CBrush brush;
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(color);
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    GetWindowRect(&rc);
    CClientDC dc(this);
    dc.SelectObject(&rc);
    if (color != GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW)) {
        dc.FillRect(rc, &brush);
    } else {
        MessageBox(_T("Same Color."), MB_OK);
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

It's tracing the document's color but not changing it, it's changing the whole window's color.

Update: I've tried the `invalidateRect` function, this is the result:
[image]

It seems like it's adding color on top of my MDI client area not in it in the background like i intended,

Comment: Does this help? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18386/Change-the-background-color-of-the-frame-area-of-a

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
void CMainFrame::OnButColor() 
{
     HBRUSH hBrush=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,255));
     SetClassLong(m_hWndMDIClient, BGCL_HBRBACKGROUND,(LONG)hBrush);
     ::InvalidateRect(m_hWndMDIClient,0,TRUE);
}
```